# I want to change a number with 5 decimal places in the form "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss."

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to change the data 20220718.20154 to 2022-07-18 20:15:40 in dataframe.
So I wrote the code below.

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.6f}'.format
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d.%H%M%S', errors='coerce')
print(df["date"])
```

but, this outputs

```
0     2022-07-18 10:34:02
1     2022-07-18 10:03:04
2     2022-07-18 20:15:04
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.ljust`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html) for add `0` if less like 15 characters from left side:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].astype(str).str.ljust(15, '0'), format='%Y%m%d.%H%M%S', errors='coerce')
```